# setting margin-bottom on div not working

Tags: css

I have a div box which I've positioned on the right hand side of the browser, the top border is fine, but I need the bottom of the box to be 140px off the bottom of the browser and I can't seem to get this to work.

Ay ideas?

```css
#nav-right {
 position: absolute;
 top:120px;
 bottom: 140px;
 right: 0;
 width: 120px;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you might need to add padding/margin to the container for this box. The 140px bottom means that it should be 140px from the bottom, but you have an item that's 100% of the height offset from the top by 120px. i'm curious if you remove the top, does the bottom show up? I might try making sure it's a block element and removing the height. https://jsfiddle.net/sc06odhg/

Comment: top:120px + height:100% and bottom:140px is not coherant .  top and bottom make it height:100%; - (120px + 140px);  !!?!!

Comment: does the box need to be positioned w/ absolute positioning. If not, i would suggest putting padding on the parent and then letting your box be 100% w/ the `box-sizing: border-box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is over-constrained because you specify definite lengths for `top`, `height` and `bottom`.

Two constraints are enough. Don't specify a `height`, let it be the default `auto`.

```css
#nav-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 140px;
  right: 0;
  width: 120px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-right"></div>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 140px;
    right: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: calc(100% - 120px - 140px);
}
```

Comment: it will closest parent set absolute, fixed or relative position to set bottom value, if no parent positionned, it takes html for reference. I think OP is not giving all relevant infos to be helpfull. Your 'fixe' is suffering of same behavior i believe